# Beautiful soup/python won't get out of a while loop

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to build my first ever webscraper, so excuse me for the mess that is my code.

However I'm running into a problem where my program get stuck in my while loop.

I want to iterate over the total number of pages. So I thought that that should be doable with a while loop:

```
While huidigePagina (means current page in dutch) <= totalePagina:
    ...
    ...
    huidigePagina = huidigePagina + 1
```

However even after the '+ 1' my while loop keeps going.
Or when it works, I get an error that my soup.find ran into a NoneType...
I've tried breaking out of the while loop but that didn't work either.

Here is the code what it's all about:

```
links = []
GeoCodes = []
coordinaten = []

content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")

for body in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'span-20 last'}):
    numberPages = body.find('div', {'id': 'ctl00_ContentBody_ResultsPanel'}).find('table', {'class': 'NoBottomSpacing'}).findAll('b')
    print(numberPages)
    huidigePagina = 1
    totalePagina = int(numberPages[2].text)

    while huidigePagina <= totalePagina:
        for row in soup.findAll('tr', {"class":["SolidRow Data BorderTop", "BeginnerRow Data BorderTop", "AlternatingRow Data BorderTop"]}):
            checkbox = row.find('td').input
            if checkbox is not None:
                cacheCodeLocator = row.find("td", {"class": "Merge"}).findNextSibling("td").text
                #print(cacheCodeLocator)
                if "GC" in cacheCodeLocator:
                     b = cacheCodeLocator
                     c = re.findall("GC.....", b)
                     GeoCodes.append(c[0])

                cachePage = row.find("td", {"class": "Merge"}).findNextSibling("td").a['href']
                if cachePage is not None:
                    driver.get(str(cachePage))
                    coordcontent = driver.page_source
                    coordinatenpagina = BeautifulSoup(coordcontent, features="html.parser")
                    coordinaat = coordinatenpagina.find('div', class_='span-9').p.span.strong.span.text
                    coordinaten.append(coordinaat)
                    driver.back()
                links.append(cachePage)
                #driver.get(str(Cachepage))

        nextPage = len(numberPages) - 1
        print(huidigePagina, totalePagina)
        if huidigePagina != totalePagina:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentBody_ResultsPanel']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[{}]".format(nextPage)).click()
        content2 = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content2, features="html.parser")
        body2 = soup.find('div', {'class': 'span-20 last'})
        numberPages = body2.find('div', {'id': 'ctl00_ContentBody_ResultsPanel'}).find('table', {'class': 'NoBottomSpacing'}).findAll('b')
        print(numberPages)
        huidigePagina = huidigePagina + 1
        totalePagina = int(numberPages[2].text)
        print(huidigePagina, totalePagina)
        if huidigePagina == totalePagina:
            break

df = pd.DataFrame({'GeoCodes': GeoCodes, 'links': links, 'coordinaten': coordinaten})
df.to_csv('C_And_C.csv', index=True, encoding='utf-8')

driver.close()
```

Here is some updated code which seems to work?

```
links = []
GeoCodes = []
coordinaten = []

content = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, features="html.parser")
for body in soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'span-20 last'}):
    numberPages = body.find('div', {'id': 'ctl00_ContentBody_ResultsPanel'}).find('table', {'class': 'NoBottomSpacing'}).findAll('b')
    print(numberPages)
    huidigePagina = 1
    totalePagina = int(numberPages[2].text)

    while huidigePagina <= totalePagina:
        for row in soup.findAll('tr', {"class":["SolidRow Data BorderTop", "BeginnerRow Data BorderTop", "AlternatingRow Data BorderTop"]}):
            checkbox = row.find('td').input
            if checkbox is not None:
                cacheCodeLocator = row.find("td", {"class": "Merge"}).findNextSibling("td").text
                #print(cacheCodeLocator)
                if "GC" in cacheCodeLocator:
                     b = cacheCodeLocator
                     c = re.findall("GC.....", b)
                     GeoCodes.append(c[0])

                cachePage = row.find("td", {"class": "Merge"}).findNextSibling("td").a['href']
                if cachePage is not None:
                    driver.get(str(cachePage))
                    coordcontent = driver.page_source
                    coordinatenpagina = BeautifulSoup(coordcontent, features="html.parser")
                    coordinaat = coordinatenpagina.find('div', class_='span-9').p.span.strong.span.text
                    coordinaten.append(coordinaat)
                    driver.back()
                links.append(cachePage)
                #driver.get(str(Cachepage))

        nextPage = len(numberPages) - 1
        huidigePagina = huidigePagina + 1
        if huidigePagina > totalePagina:
            break
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_ContentBody_ResultsPanel']/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[2]/a[{}]".format(nextPage)).click()
        content2 = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(content2, features="html.parser")
        body2 = soup.find('div', {'class': 'span-20 last'})
        numberPages = body2.find('div', {'id': 'ctl00_ContentBody_ResultsPanel'}).find('table', {'class': 'NoBottomSpacing'}).findAll('b')
        print(numberPages)
        totalePagina = int(numberPages[2].text)
        print(huidigePagina, totalePagina)


df = pd.DataFrame({'GeoCodes': GeoCodes, 'links': links, 'coordinaten': coordinaten})
df.to_csv('C_And_C.csv', index=True, encoding='utf-8')

driver.close()
```

Comment: What is `print(huidigePagina, totalePagina)` printing (when it should have ended)?

Comment: Yes exactly it was just for troubleshooting reasons. Seeing if the current page number is equal to the amount of total pages

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But what does it print? This should point you in the direction why both the while-loop doesn't terminate and the break doesn't work.

Comment: Is it because those variabeles are outside the while loop?

Comment: They aren't outside the while loop. But what does `print(huidigePagina, totalePagina)` print?

Comment: Well at their current positition in the code they are printing: 1 2 (the first pass), then 2 2 (second pass), then 2 2 (third pass acompannied by an error where NoneType has no attribute 'find')

But if that wasn't what you meant and you meant that they print, one hard coded value (i thought that that might work... it didn't) and one variable (based on the third entry of the list 'numberPages')

But I'm probably just thinking too complicated for the solution... Does it have something to do with the order of my while loop?

Comment: I don't get how `huidigePagina` can be `2` two times. First: it should be incremented by 1 every time and secondly: it should `break` since it is equal to `totalePagina`... Since it is 2 again in the third print, the while loop doesn't terminate because it is not bigger than `totalePagina`, but it seems like it should have been 3...

Comment: I ran the test again (copying the code I've posted above) and you're right, first pass it is: 1 2, second pass it is 2 2 acompanied by an error....  Also, I saw I printed the `huidigePagina` en `totalePagina` twice which seemed weird.... When I remove the upper one the output is only: 2 2 once and then the accompanied error:
`numberPages = body.find('div', {'id': 'ctl00_ContentBody_ResultsPanel'}).find('table', {'class': 'NoBottomSpacing'}).findAll('b')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'`

But also yes I didn't get either how it didn't break on 3...

Comment: Also I've added some updated code. does the while loop now work correctly? Or is the error connected to the while loop?

Comment: So in the second call, one of your two `find` calls doesn't contain the item you are looking for. Maybe split them into two lines, so you now which `find` doesn't contain anything.

Comment: YES! Thank you! Finally got it to work, I had to move the if statement up and had to add another one, but it works! Thanks!